# How to return information with PHP from an AJAX request?

Tags: php, ajax

I've been learning about AJAX and making my first requests from my local server, only requesting an XML or HTML file, nothing too difficult. I'm working with PHP now, and I understand it fairly well, it's not too much different than using the XML/HTML.

While going through tutorials I've seen a few different ways of returning information back to JavaScript; I am curious as to whether or not there is a 'right' way, or even a 'more correct' way of doing this. Thus far I have come across three methods:

someFile.php:

```
<?php
$foo = $_GET['bar'];

// manipulate $foo

exit($foo); // method 1
echo $foo;  // method 2

// method 3:
?>

<div id='baz'>
    <p>
        Some output to be returned to JavaScript as the 'responseText'
        property of the AJAX request.
    </p>
    <p>
        <?php echo $foo ?>
    </p>
</div>
```

I'm simply unsure of the process of returning information from the server back to the browser. What all gets sent back? Anything that would be displayed if this were a page that people were actually supposed to visit? Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to look at PHP scripts as programs that generates HTML / JSON / XML documents that the browser requested. In AJAX, the browser does just the same: it request the document for a certain URL. Only it might just be a fragment, or JSON that you will integrate into the page using JavaScript.

As for AJAX in general, neither approach is more correct, even though I haven't seen the "exit(...)" approach so far. Whatever generates a document will work.

Regarding best practices, you might eventually want to seperate your calculations from the generation of the documents. But I'd guess you should first gain more experience with basic PHP, HTML, AJAX, etc. When the applications you write become so big that you start to have difficulties to find your way around your code, you might want to look at MVC frameworks for PHP, which solve the problem of separating calculations (business / model logic) and document generation (views). I hear Symfony is a popular one.

Comment: So, to be sure, the page that gets sent back from PHP would be received as responseText on the AJAX request, correct? Thank you for your explanation, it really made me go 'duh!'

Comment: I suppose "responseText" is the variable that you write your AJAX response into? In that case, yes. In jQuery, that would be the "data" parameter passed to the "success" callback function.

Answer (score 1):

I usually have more than one value to send back from the server so I use:

```
<?php echo json_encode(array('name' => 'Michael', 'email' => 'michael@example.com'); ?>
```

I can then access them easily like an object.

```
alert(response.name);
```

Try using a JS library such as jQuery. It makes it pretty easy.

Answer (score 0):

What i always do is

```
<?php
header('Content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');
echo $foo;
exit;
?>
```

(yes i know in this example i don't need to use `exit`)

Comment: so out of curiosity, why do you add the exit?

Comment: It's just me. I'm sure there will be no white space in response.

Comment: okok. it just me, but I hate to see stuff that do "nothing" in the code, as I spend time to try to understand why the hell it's here... overall when **I** did put it there ;)

Answer (score -1):

If you want to allow people to access the page directly then the above code works fine. But if you want to secure the page jut put on the top of the page if (_POST['somevalue'] == 'login') and from $ajax send data in POST. Remaining part is same if you know e.g in jQuery ajax onSuccess $(div).html(data) !!